# How should we deal with human factor based race conditions, with regards to accidental edits?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

<sub>(disclaimer: a quick search for "accidental edit" did not bring up anything useful IMO, but I don't think that this is an uncommon problem -- if there's a dupe, CVs are welcome.)</sub>

So, here is [the revision history of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21073459/revisions). As you can see, the original post was pretty badly worded with quite a few typos and spelling errors. Those have been fixed by user Suin, but I didn't find his changes substantial enough, so I have also opted to edit the post, trimming the trailing "thanks".

However, in the meantime the OP has changed his post as well, and by the time I hit Submit, OP's edits have already been committed. So my edit has undone those. This is bad, because the edits improved the post (he clarified his question), and I didn't want to vandalize that. What's even worse, I didn't have any notification or warning as to what was happening.

I remember having done the same a couple of times before, and I've always managed to restore OP's edits manually, by looking at the revisions, but this sort of manual merge is tedious and the day has come when I've got fed up with it.

So my questions are:

- What should I do to avoid these situations?
- What should I do when I accidentally run into such a case?
- Could some sort of improvement be made to the site so that users who are currently editing a post can get notified if parallel modifications occur?

Comment: @rene No, it was a question I've come across, it was under `/questions`.

Comment: `What should I do to avoid these situations?` Wait - which I myself don't do anyway. `What should I do when I accidentally run into such a case?` Manual merge, like you are doing. `Could some sort of improvement be made to the site so that users who are currently editing a post can get notified if parallel modifications occur?` There was something like this (or was there?), but it forces the editor to refresh and abandon the edit attempt and redo it later.

Comment: One thing to avoid that specific example: people should respect the grace period? The OP saved their edit 3.5 minutes after their original question.

Comment: And I'm confused: you saw your edit accidentally removed something, but did not merge the missing detail, or rollback your edit?

Comment: @Arjan Ugh, actually, not yet. (Partly because I wanted to know what I should do from now on.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Hi where are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Edit History.

Every editor change results in a new revision (irrespective of the grace period).  If you've stepped on someone else's edits, just rollback to the revision history before yours to restore them.